# Не могу перевести на русский: "Functions are a first-class type"

Tags: swift, терминология

> “Functions are a first-class type. This means that a function can return another function as its value.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.0.1).” iBooks. https://itun.es/ua/jEUH0.l”

Функция является **Каким-то там типом**. Под этим подразумевается, что функция может вернуть другую функцию как значение(скорее всего значение возвращаемое ею).

**Что тогда Second-class type?** (и есть ли вообще такой)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где Вы взяли Second-class type? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: Исключительно моя воспаленная фантазия.(почему-то мне кажется, что если есть тип первого класса, то должен быть и второго.) Теоретически его может не быть =(

Comment: это обычное явление для современных языков, когда функции могут вести себя как обычные переменные. Это решает проблему голых указателей на функции.

Comment: Полностью согласен с вашим утверждением, Вопрос только в том как "First-class type" сказать по русски и быть правильно понятым. Возможно есть какой-то устоявшийся термин(желательно встречающийся в более менее извесных книгах вроде Страуструпа или Банды четырех)

Comment: я же привел ссылку на википедею

Comment: У вас скриншот закончился на самом интересном месте. `Функция - первоклассный тип. Это значит, что функция может вернуть ...` `может вернуть ...`. `вернуть может функция ...`. В общем ясно, что на этом пояснение первоклассности обрывается и остаётся загадкой. Что же там написано дальше?

Comment: Sergey, полная версия находится в первой строке описания. “Functions are a first-class type. This means that a function can return another function as its value.”

Comment: [Функции высшего порядка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Объектами первого класса (англ. first-class object, first-class entity, first-class citizen) в контексте конкретного языка программирования называются элементы, которые могут быть переданы как параметр, возвращены из функции, присвоены переменной.

В swift функции являются объектами первого класса, т.е. их можно передать как параметр, вернуть их других функций или присвоить переменной.

В вашем случае перевод будет: Функции являются объектами первого класса. Это значит, что функция может вернуть другую функцию.

UPDATE

Немного дополнительной информации:
такая классификация была придумана Рафаэлем Финкелем (Raphael Finkel). Он выделил три вида объектов:

- first class object - может быть передан как параметр, возвращен из функции, присвоен переменной
- second class object - может быть передан как параметр, но не возвращен и не может быть присвоен переменной.
- third class object - нельзя делать ничего из выше описанного.

Такая классификация не применима ко всем языкам программирования, потому что язык не обязательно имеет все три, или даже два типа объектов из этого списка. По этому first class object превратился во что-то вроде устойчивого выражения.

Comment: Всё что возвращает функция называется объектами первого класса? А если нет такого объекта, который не могла бы вернуть функция? Тогда же всё первого класса! Какой смысл тогда в этом понятии? Оно не может быть применено как какой-то отличительный признак одних объектов от других, раз они все такие. Если есть первый класс, значит должен быть как минимум второй, пусть о нём явно и не говорится. Но если его нет, то нет и первого. Единство и борьба противоположностей - это не только досужие философские домыслы, но и суровая правда жизни.

Comment: @Sergey вам дать больше объяснений или вы просто троллите?

Comment: Объясните, если не трудно. Вот например даже в паскале и тем более c|c++ можно возвращать функцию, но я не припомню там такого понятия как "первый класс" в отношении чего-либо. Кажется кто-то придумывает понятия на совершенно пустом месте.

Comment: @Sergey вкратце, придумал такую классификацию Рафаэль Финкель, объект первого класса - см ответ, второго класса - может быть использован как параметр функции но не возвращенное значение, и не может быть присвоен переменной, третьего класса - нельзя делать ничего указанного выше. Все это дело варьируется от языка, и вполне может быть, что в некоторых языках существуют только объекты первого класса, по этому эта классификация в этих языках не используется.

Comment: Наверное это надо написать в ответе

Comment: @Sergey честно вам скажу, у меня уже почти час ночи. завтра обязательно испаравлю

Comment: А примеры на каждую разновидность можно?

Comment: @Qwertiy честно гуглил, но что то ничего не нашел. например, как мы уже знаем из вопроса - в swift функция это first class, насколько я понимаю, в java функция это second class. а вот third class я что то затрудняюсь придумать.

Comment: Почему в джаве функция second? Вроде как всё, что может быть передано, может быть и возвращено. До недавнего времени в шарпе ссылки было нельзя возвращать - вроде подходит на второй класс. А вот что можно делать с третьим, я что-то вообще придумать не могу.

Comment: @Qwerty, что значит 'ссылки нельзя возвращать'?

Comment: @Qwertiy в swift функция может принять функцию как входной параметр и может вернуть функцию. я так понимаю в джава такой фокус не получается.

Comment: @hardsky `ref int Test(ref int x)` - вроде сейчас уже можно, но было нельзя.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, передача функции - это передача реализации функционального интерфейса. Вернуть реализацию функционального интерфейса тоже можно. Либо я что-то в определении не понимаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy я в джаве не силен. был под впечатлением, что там такое сделать нельзя.

Comment: @Qwertiy, массивы  в Си (те, для которых работает sizeof) очевидно объекты третьего класса.

Comment: Raphael Finkel предложил 2-й и 3-й класс только в 1990-ом году, и его особо не поддержали (если верить вики). А разделение на first class / second class ввел Christopher Strachey еще в 60-х. first-class citizen - это просто "пользующиеся всеми правами" или "полноценные" в плане возможностей. В противовес дискриминированным Second-class citizen.

Comment: @avp, а разве нельзя параметр объявить типа `int a[5]`? например

Comment: @Grundy, объявить можно, но суть не изменится, передается указатель, а не полноценный массив. Например для `int f(int a[5]) { ...` компилятор явно предупреждает: `warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘a’ will return size of ‘int *’`. / Да и все эти рассуждения, как мне представляется, наукоподобная болтовня, которая ничего  практике программирования не дает.

Answer (score 3):

Дословный перевод термина "First Class [Citizen]" на русский - это "полноправный [гражданин]". Термин был скопирован из социологии, где [Second Class Citizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-class_citizen) означает человека с урезанными правами, дискриминированного члена общества.

Например, first-class polymorphism означает "полноценный/полноправный полиморфизим" (а не "жалкое его подобие :). first-class type - полноценный тип, "такой же как object".

На практике утверждение "Функции - [First Class Types/Citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen)" применительно к конкретному языку означает что функции в нем являются объектами (экземплярами типов).

Например, в C# вы не можете написать код вроде:

```
int MyFunction()
{
   //  
}

var somevariable = MyFunction;
```

т.к. в нем есть строгое разделение на типы и их методы.

Но при этом в Javascript вы вполне можете написать аналогичный код, и он отработает без ошибок.

```
function MyFunction()
{

}

var myvariable = MyFunction;
```

Более того, т.к. функция в JS является полноценным объектом, вы можете делать с ней совершенно дикие вещи, например задавать у нее свойства:

```
MyFunction.someProp = 42;
```

Разделение между First Class / Second Class довольно условное, и строгой устоявшейся терминологии нет. Были попытки  ввести строгое разделение на 2-3 и более классов, но они широкого распространения не получили. Это все довольно подробно описано в википедии по ссылке выше.

Comment: разве не можем в c#: _somevariable = MyFunction;_? а делегаты?

Comment: @Grundy делегаты - это не сами функции. Это костыль для устранения  не-first class. Вы же не можете работать с самой функцией как с объектом. MyFunction.ToString() - не взлетит.